Error after upgrading angular 17 to 18, maximum call stack error by colorette
I have upgraded my version from angular 17 to 18.
I am trying to run ng serve or ng build and getting the error below.

\app\node_modules\listr2\node_modules\colorette\index.cjs:54
head = string.substring(0, index) + replace, ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at String.substring
(<anonymous>) at replaceClose (C:\Users\E02973\Desktop\n6 - Copy
(2)\app\node_modules\listr2\node_modules\colorette\index.cjs:54:17)
at replaceClose (C:\Users\E02973\Desktop\n6 -
Copy(2)\app\node_modules\listr2\node_modules\colorette\index.cjs:57:32)
at replaceClose (C:\Users\E02973\Desktop\n6 - Copy
(2)\app\node_modules\listr2\node_modules\colorette\index.cjs:57:32)
at replaceClose (C:\Users\E02973\Desktop\n6 - Copy
(2)\app\node_modules\listr2\node_modules\colorette\index.cjs:57:32)
at replaceClose (C:\Users\E02973\Desktop\n6 - Copy
(2)\app\node_modules\listr2\node_modules\colorette\index.cjs:57:32)
Node.js v20.17.0


When I am running the application, the colorette issue should not occur. If I use some old version but there some auto dependencies on new version I can not be modify them.

looks like the package colorette is causing problem with the upgrade have you removed node modules cleared the cache and install everything back again?you can also try upgrading colorette package if an upgrade exist

I have upgraded colorette package , delete node modules and package-lock.json and reinstall  node packages . but still getting same error. Because some of colorette packages install by itself with own versions . please help me

is colorette mandatory in your project.Your facing the nmp package hell where you are dependent of maitainers

One other soltuion would be to create a fork of colorette and make modifications

If I remove the colorette package from my project But colorette automatically install with another packages. Second one how can I create fork with any dependency.

This is not necessary. But still it remains in the package.lock.json file in the project. Even if we remove it from the package.json file, I am not able to remove it. This is a feature of Angular 18.

have you used https://angular.dev/update-guide?v=17.0-18.0&l=1 to update your application?

yes, I used same

can you share the code with a github or something like that?or is this private?

its private for my orgenization

I'm sorry but I won't be able to help you more if I don't have at least a minimal reproducible example

Colorette is not the cause of the error, it's just a tool that helps format the actual errors.
What I did is open node_modules/colorette/index.cjs and replace the replaceClose method with this (adding a console.log)
const replaceClose = (
  index,
  string,
  close,
  replace,
  head = string.substring(0, index) + replace,
  tail = string.substring(index + close.length),
  next = tail.indexOf(close)
) => {
  console.log(index, string, close, replace);
  return head + (next < 0 ? tail : replaceClose(next, tail, close, replace));
}

This will log tons of messages, but they will be the actual error and not the colorette error.

Increasing the stack size helped in my case.
node --stack_size=2048 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --configuration=dev

